# How Get Message from TCP/IP Python?

Tags: python

how do I get the message that more than two messages in the buffer in the TCP / IP connection in python if I use the XML-RPC. I've tried using Cherrypy if the message is received by a normal state if more than one it will not get the message.

Answer (score 0):

About the best answer you will get is to switch framework to twisted. Twisted makes networking laughable because of its simplicity

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/xmlrpc.html

Here is a tutorial for xml rpc using twisted.